# ¿Cómo llenar un DatagridView de C# con Mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Estoy algo atorado al llenar mi `DataGrid` con datos de MongoDB. Estos son mis avances:

```
    protected static IMongoClient cliente = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
    protected static IMongoDatabase data = cliente.GetDatabase("base");

    private void Formulario_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("empleados");
        var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
        var cursor = coleccion.Find(filtro);
        var listado = cursor.ToList();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("nombre", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("rol", typeof(string));

        foreach (var item in listado)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item["nombre"]);
            dt.Rows.Add(item["rol"]);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Esta es una Impresion de pantalla, de cómo me muestra los datos:

[image: Mostrar Imagen]

Comment: hola ! bienvenid@ a SOes, podrías aclarar el inconveniente que estás teniendo?

Comment: No me muestra los datos de manera correcta, creo que el problema esta al poner el cursos.ToList(), hee buscado un poco y parece que deberia utilizar MongoCursos pero aun nno entiendo la sintaxis.

Comment: Aqui tienes un ejemplo para pasar los datos de un BsonDocument a un DataTable   [programingqa](http://www.programingqa.com/post/Converting-MongoDB-query-result-to-C-ADONET-DataTable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la forma en que solucione mi problema, espero alguien le sea util.
Saludos

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

    namespace Administrador
    {
    public partial class FrmTodos : Form
    {
    public FrmTodos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string rol { get; set; }
        public string ruta { get; set; }
    }

    private void FrmTodos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("base_datos");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("empleados");
        BindingList<Entity> doclist = new BindingList<Entity>();
        foreach (var deger in collection.FindAll())
        {
            doclist.Add(deger);

            string[] row1 = new string[] { deger.nombre.ToString() };
            string[] row2 = new string[] { deger.rol.ToString() };
            string[] row3 = new string[] { deger.ruta.ToString() };     

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row2);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row3);
            Application.DoEvents();

        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = doclist;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "IDD";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Nombre";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Rol";
    }
```

Comment: no tendrias que haber cargado los datos por medio del Rows.Add() eso no es correcto, estaba bien asignar el DataSource es mas puedes asignar el doclist  directo al grid

Comment: ese codigo es incorrecto, si usas el Rows.Add() no usas el DataSource es uno u otro

Answer (score 1):

Si inspeccionas el DataTable que asignas el grid puedes ver que la columan de rol tiene datos, usa la tecnica descripta en el articulo para validarlo:

[Debugging Data Tables in Visual Studio](http://johngraybosch.com/2014/06/24/debugging-datatables-in-visual-studio/)

Si descartamos el punto anterior entonces

- podrias probar de asignar la propiedad AutoGenerateColumns = true de esta forma automaticamente generara las columnas segun los datos. Esto permite validar que el dato que asignas al grid esta correcto
- si defines las columnas en tiempo de diseño recuerda asignar la propiedad `DataPropertyName` con el nombre de la columna, en este caso "rol" ya que sino lo haces el grid no sabra como mapear el dato con la columan del grid y la mostrara vacia

Answer (score 0):

He utilizado mis datos
`mRUTAMONGODB`: reemplazar esta variable por su base de datos

```
var dbClient = new MongoClient(mRUTAMONGODB);
IMongoDatabase dbVinc = dbClient.GetDatabase("vinculacion");

var correos = dbVinc.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("correos");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
            
var cursor = correos.Find(filter);
var listado = cursor.ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
dt.Columns.Add("SECUENCIAL", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CEDULA_IDENTIDAD", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CORREO", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("APELLIDOS", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("NOMBRES", typeof(string));

int cont = 0;
foreach (var item in listado)
            {
                cont++;
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["SECUENCIAL"] = cont.ToString();
                row["CEDULA_IDENTIDAD"] = item["CEDULA_IDENTIDAD"];
                row["CORREO"] = item["CORREO"];
                row["APELLIDOS"] = item["APELLIDOS"];
                row["NOMBRES"] = item["NOMBRES"];

                dt.Rows.Add(row);

}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```