# ¿Cómo llenar un combobox con MongoDB y C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Tengo algunos problemas con llenar mi combobox con los datos de un document en MongoDB, usando c#.

Además, necesito asociar el dato que se muestra con su valor.

Estos han sido mis avances:

- En la primer línea dentro de mi foreach me muestra los datos, pero no sus valores.
- En la segunda se muestra tanto su valor como su dato.
- En la tercer linea uso `DisplayMember` pero no me muestra nada.

```
private void llenar_combobox()
{
    var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("companies");
    var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
    var cursor = coleccion.Find(filtro);
    var listado = cursor.ToList();
    foreach (var item in listado)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(item["nombre"]);
        //comboBox1.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item["nombre"].ToString(),item["nombre"].ToString()));
        //comboBox1.DisplayMember =item["nombre"].ToString();
        //comboBox1.ValueMember = item["_id"].ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: pero ya tienes una pregunta sobre el mismo tema  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26251/como-llenar-un-datagridview-de-c-con-mongodb   cargar un combo o un grid es lo mismo, tienes que asignar los datos a un objeto ya sea una lista o datatable y luego asignas este al DataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres hacer usando objeto entonces primero define la clase

```
public class company
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string nombre {get;set;}
}
```

y luego con la ayuda de linq seria

```
private void llenar_combobox()
{
    var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("companies");
    var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
    var cursor = coleccion.Find(filtro);
    var listado = cursor.ToList();

    var listCompanies = listado.Select(x=> new company()
    {
        id = item["_id"].ToString(),
        nombre = item["nombre"].ToString()
    }).ToList();

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "nombre";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
    comboBox1.DataSource = listCompanies;

}
```

como veras conviertes la lista de la db a la lista del tipo que has creado para asignar luego al datasource del combo

Comment: Muchas Dobles gracias por tu ayuda Leandro Tuttini, me has hecho un enorme favor. Saludos Cordiales

Answer (score 0):

id = item["_id"].ToString(),
        nombre = item["nombre"].ToString()

La variable item, de que parte deriva?

Comment: ["_id"] es el nombre de la columna de la colección?

Comment: Por favor no uses la zona de respuestas para exponer dudas o comentarios, lee [answer]